# Screen lock button doesn't silence UILocalNotification sound

Tags: iphone

I have an application that uses the UILocalNotification when in the background to alert the user to open the app when something of interest happens. The notification plays a sound (specified using the soundName property). This is all okay however, is there a way to stop the UILocalNotification sound when the user presses the screen lock button?

I found the users are used to pressing this button to silence the phone's ringtone without answering it and they expect to do the same with my app.

Answer (score 0):

UILocalNotifications, to my knowledge, do not make a persistant sound.
If yours does, it's likely in conflict with Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.

However, just because you shouldn't doesn't mean you shouldn't know how:

One method would be to change the soundName property of your notifications in the AppDelegate method `applicationWillResignActive:`

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    self.myLocalNotif.soundName = @"";
    ...
    //clean up anything else before entering the background
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by persistant sound? My app runs in the background, and the UILocalNotification is used to have the user bring it to the forefront. The UILocalNotification specifies a soundName to play when displayed. I want to be able to turn this sound off (immedialtely) if the screen lock button is pressed but I don't see how this can be done?

Comment: The sound shouldn't be long enough to allow that sort of behavior. Ergo, there's probably not a (legal) way to do it.

Comment: The sound is < 30 seconds. I just want to be able to turn it off immediately when the screen lock button is pressed - just like the cell ringtone can be silenced immediately when the screen lock button is pressed.